# How to introduce EF-migrations into existing mature project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

In short, what I am trying to do, is add the power of migrations into a project that is mature and changes always been handled manually using sql.

I have been assigned a project that uses Entity Framework, but all database-changes were done manually without using migrations.

Earlier when new changes were introduced we would create the models in code, update the context with new tables, then use Entity Framework PowerTools to generate the sql and then update the database manually.

So today we have a complete database, we have a databasecontext, as well as carefully crafted EntityTypeConfiguration classes. So this is a code-first situation, but the database already exists.

The challenge is that after I run

```
'Enable-Migrations'
'Add-Migration'
```

I am stuck with a complete Up() function that tried to create the entire database if I do

```
'Update-Database'.
```

What I think I want to do is set a flag in the database that the current state is the status-quo, and that my current Up() function only will be used when creating a brand new database.

After that I want all changes to the database be handled by EF-migrations.

Is this possible? and how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it not possible that now you have a complete database, to remove all migration scripts and create a new Init script, and work from this point going forward?

Comment: EF migrations are the weakest form of migration, really only meant for development. They are no substitute for migration scripts generated by hand or a migration tool like Redgate's. Adding a new column is easy, but what about migrating *data*? How can you handle date splitting? You may end up writing as much code as you would in a migration script

Comment: Using _EF migrations_ with production databases is quite dangerous. I would not recommend doing it and Microsoft does neither :) I use the SQL Tools in VisualStudio that allow to compare and selectively migrate database schema and table data.

Comment: It's a fair point that doing migrations in production is a bad idea, and maybe I should have added that the reason I am doing this is to simplify creating a database locally for development. Earlier this project had one developer, and everything was fine with one database. Now more people are working on it and I want people to have their own databases for development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OPTION 1: Create migration that starts from the current model**

You can use the `–IgnoreChanges` parameter with `Add-Migration` command:

```
Add-Migration MigrationName –IgnoreChanges
```

This creates an empty migration with the current model as a snapshot.

**OPTION 2: Create full migrations that create database from scratch, but skip the first migration on some databases**

Entity Framework uses `__MigrationHistory` table to keep track of migrations that have already been executed. When the first migration is executed on the database, it gets inserted in `__MigrationHistory` table. Next time `Update-Database` command is called, EF looks at `__MigrationHistory` table and skips the migrations that are already applied to the database.

To make a specific database skip the first migration, you can do the following:

1. Create the initial migration:

```
Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

2. Get the migration script, using the following command:

```
Update-Database -Script
```

3. Delete everything from the above script, except the following statements:

```
CREATE TABLE [__MigrationHistory]
```

```
INSERT INTO [__MigrationHistory] ...
```

and execute these statements on the database.

Now this database has the information that the `InitialCreate` migration has already been applied, and any further calls to `Update-Database` against this specific database will skip the `InitialCreate` migration.

Comment: While this is a good tips, it's not exacly what I want because the Up() function is now empty. Meaning I can't use it to create a local database from scratch.

But if there is a similar thing for update-database, that would be awesome.

Comment: @Thomas I updated the answer to cover this scenario as well.

Comment: Very good answer. I have marked this as the correct answer for future questions.